# In-memory SQL Server log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, performance-tuning

I have a SQL Server instance that is used solely for the purpose of reporting and also for preparing data to be loaded into Analysis Services.  Its data comes from another SQL Server instance which is the production instance.

As this database can be rebuilt at any time from the production OLTP database, we've been thinking about putting its log file in memory (using something like RAMDisk).

I've done just that and, to my surprise, we haven't gained much performance; it's become only about 2x better.

Given that I'm no longer writing the log to disk, why is the performance gain this low?  The CPU is not reaching anywhere near 100%.  Where is the bottleneck now?

**Note: We have also tested successfully with minimally logged operations using the trace flag 610, but for the purpose of this question please just ignore this.**

Comment: What recovery mode is your DW db set to?

Comment: @EricHiggins SIMPLE.

Comment: can you clear the wait stats on both source and destination instance and then run the load again. After that, please collect the wait statistics on both instances with this query: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts.aspx

Comment: you clear the wait stats using the following (just in case): DBCC SQLPERF ('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR);

Comment: If you're still writing the data to disk, why do you expect more than 2X performance improvement?

Comment: I must be misreading this... if this is a reporting database that you don't write too, why would there be any performance gain from optimising the transaction log?

Comment: @EdwardDortland will do!

Comment: @AaronBertrand because I'm only writing the data file to disk, not logs. In fact the disk where the data file is almost always idle when I load the data in, except for steep spikes of writes (that is to be expected).

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith you are.

Comment: @ivanmp Thanks for the clarification. Good luck.

Comment: And do you think the steep spikes in writes are free, and that eliminating log contention will make a massive data load happen on a regular I/O subsystem perform instantaneously? I'll echo what @MarkStorey-Smith said: good luck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand definitely not free, otherwise I wouldn't have spoken about them. The disk sits idle most of the time. I don't know what I'm missing, but that's the point of asking the question, isn't it? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated the methodology you're loading your DW database with, but you may be seeing quite a bit of logging due to IDENTITY values per [this blog](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/isselectidentityintominimallyloggedinsimplerecovery).